# Locked out of my NAS - 2FA codes don't work while I'm abroad

Tags: nas, login, synology, synology-diskstation, two-factor-authentication

I'm currently abroad. I have my Synology NAS set up in my apartment. While still there I set up a 2FA on it for my admin account.

I remember a while back when I was trying to log in to it, it didn't recognize my 2FA codes. So I had to reset my password. At that time I was busy with something else and didn't want to deal with it then.

So now today when I was trying to log in to it, and entered my user name and password:

[image]

It went straight into this:

[image]

Aand when I set it up (by scanning the QR code shown with my Google Authenticator app) and by entering the code, I keep getting this message:

> Code authentication failed. Please make sure the secret key you entered is correct or try synchronizing the system time of your mobile device and DSM.

[image]

What the heck is that? Why are my 2FA codes not working? (I hope whoever coded those 2FA codes had some brains to use UTC time and didn't use the "local" time to compute them, and also used some automatic way to sync time on the NAS itself.)

And the main question now - how do I get back into my NAS?

PS. After posting this I tried to install Google Authenticator app on my Android phone and then changed the time zone (manually) to the one that DSM is running on and tried the steps above to set up 2FA. And it still gave me the same error.

Comment: There's a NTP clock issue, either on the NAS or the smartphone _(rebooting both normally fixes clock issues)_. 2FA isn't the same from one device/service to the next, as when it's implemented on the server, settings determine what codes are acceptable _(e.g. one code before the time expiration [two active codes], one code before and one after [three active codes], etc.)_, of which is time-based. Generally, motherboards use UTC and it's the OS that applies the +/- hours, so it sounds like the system clock on the NAS is off _(you'd generally know on a smartphone since encryption wouldn't work)_

Comment: _Cont'd..._ Generally, the 2FA and passphrase are sent at the same time, and the last screenshot indicates it may be the the system time on one or the other is off by enough milliseconds that encryption is failing

Comment: @JW0914 ok, so how do I reboot it remotely?

Comment: You likely can't if you can't login, unless you have SSH configured _(I've never used Synology, so I'd refer to the manual/their site)_ - if you don't have anyone that can physically reboot it, I would email Synology tech support to determine if there is a way to remotely reboot it without logging in. If you have it powered via a UPS and that UPS is managed via software on a different machine or router, power down the UPS remotely, then power it back on